# What is the meaning of thermodynamic tendency?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrochemistry

While giving a test, I encountered a question which was as follows

> Lead reduces $\ce{NO_3^-}$ into $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{NO_2}$ depending on the concentration of $\ce{HNO_3}$ in solution. Assuming that $\ce{[Pb^{2+}]} = \pu{0.1 M}$ and $p_\ce{NO} = p_\ce{NO2} = \pu{0.001 
>  bar}$ and use the following data:
>
> \begin{align}
>   E^\circ_\ce{Pb^2+/Pb} &= \pu{-0.13 V}\\
>   E^\circ_\ce{NO3^-/NO} &= \pu{0.96 V}\\
>   E^\circ_\ce{NO3^-/NO2} &= \pu{0.79 V}\\
> \end{align}
> and at $\pu{298K}$ $\frac{(2.303)RT}{F} = \pu{0.06 V}$, find the concentration of $\ce{HNO3}$ at which thermodynamic tendency for reduction of $\ce{NO3^-}$ into $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ by lead is the same.

In this question what is the meaning of thermodynamic tendency? Is it represented by $E_\mathrm{cell}$ or $\Delta G$? Quoting a reliable source would help.

The answer is $\pu{10^{0.625} M}$ which comes by equating the $E_\mathrm{cell}$ of the reactions.
My intuition told me to equate $\Delta G$ but it seems I am wrong.

Comment: How is equating Ecell different from equating ΔG?

Comment: The number of electron that are involved in the reaction are different hence equating $\ce{E_{cell}}$ and equating $\ce{\Delta{G}}$ are two different things.

Comment: Guys have tendency to be attracted to ( in their eyes ) the most beautiful girl regardless of the success. Similarly, TD systems have tendency to reach the state with the minimal Gibbs energy, regardless of if they reach it ( e.g. due kinetic reasons ). Diamonds have TD tendency to become graphite, staying being diamonds for billions years.

Comment: I am unable to understand that what are you wanting to imply?

Comment: The Hess law is applicable on $\Delta G_\mathrm{halfr}$ ( implicitly referring to SHE as the 2nd half reaction), or on its equivalent $-nF.E_\mathrm{redox}$.   // As $\Delta U = q \cdot \Delta E$ (energy, charge, potential difference )

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem, the $\Delta G$ values cannot be compared, or equalized, because they do not correspond to the same equation. Both reactions start from the same products, $\ce{Pb + NO3^-}$. But the first reaction leads to $\ce{NO}$ and the other one to $\ce{NO2}$, and these two nitrogen oxides do not have the same $G^\circ_\mathrm{form}$ values. So the Gibbs energy values are no use for solving this problem. It is much better to compare potentials through the Nernst equation.

Comment: I am not able to understand that if the $\Delta{G^o_form}$ values are different then why can't we compare the $\Delta{G}$ of both the reactions? Also then, under what circumstances the $\Delta{G}$ values of two reactions can be compared?

Comment: Are Free Energy changes not directly related to potentials?